# How to create a NON persisted model in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a model in loopback that I do not want to persist to the database. It looks (almost) like this:

```
{
    "name": "Contact",
    "base": "Model",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, how do I instantiate such a model? Can I do:

```
var contact = new app.models.Contact()
```

If I can, is this the correct way? Help is much appreciated.

Andres

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just try if you can instead of asking SO?

Comment: this is stackoverflow @IvanSchwarz

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's the correct way for building a model instance.

And if you want to persist that you can use : `contact.save()`